# HDInsight scalability when using Azure Storage

Tags: hive, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

Hi I'm playing around with HDInsight. I'm putting log files into Azure storage and then using Hive external tables to map onto them. I believe Microsoft recommend Azure storage to HDFS so you can delete and recreate the clusters without losing data. What is the scalability vs HDFS. My understanding of HDFS is that it is spread over multiple nodes to allow parallel processesing how does this compare to Azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

On HDInsight, HDFS storage is based on disks that run in the physical hosts of the VMs (PaaS VMs called worker roles in Windows Azure).

Windows Azure storage has its own scalability mechanisms. The scalability targets are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn249410.aspx
To give you an idea, Windows Azure storage is where an OS disk lives for Windows Azure IaaS VMs.